# Coldfusion:Application.cfc cflogin in script

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc, cflogin

So i work for a place that uses coldfusion and uses cflogin in a project in a application.cfm file:

```
<cflogin idletimeout="2800">
   <cfif not IsDefined("cflogin")>
    <cfinclude template="login.cfm">
    <cfabort>

  </cfif>
</cflogin>
```

I myself prefer script style and read that you should use application.CFC instead of CFM online. Im still new to Coldfusion because i come from a php background so im trying to use cflogin just like they do do in tag syntax but in script heres my code in the onRequestStart function:

```
      if(!isdefined("cflogin"))
      {

        include "/login.cfm";
        abort;
      }
      else{
        //auth code

      }
```

now im wondering how i can use cflogin in script style which seems to have been added in CF11-https://cfdocs.org/cflogin

My code in script loads the login form fine but when i submit this results in cflogin not being defined so when they hit login it just returns back to login form like the page refreshes. Im just a bit confused because if i use application.cfm file and use tag based it works but it wont work for script style?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this occur with just users connecting from an outside network, or does it also happen when running locally?

Comment: The tag based syntax works on both local and production regardless of network. Or at least from what ive tested, this seems to be the case.

Comment: In your first example you are using the CFLogin tag, which is checking your login state, but in your second example you are just checking the "cflogin" variable which is where I think the problem is.

Comment: <cfif not IsDefined("cflogin")> and if(!isdefined("cflogin"))

Are the same thing. I think whats causing my issue, is the fact that the tag syntax has the cflogin if nested inside cflogin tag but my script is not.

Im not sure how to go about using cflogin in script cfdocs.org/cflogin
Tells me there is a cflogin script cflogin(); but how do i use it?
because i cant do this:

cflogin(
  if(!isDefined("cflogin"))
  {
     ///code

  }
);

Comment: For now im using a tag based application.cfc file and it works in tag but im simply trying use script style for pure aesthetics and preference because of my php background.

Answer (score 1):

You could, instead of

```
if(not isDefined("cflogin"))
```

use

```
if(not isDefined("cflogin.name") or (isDefined("cflogin.name") and trim(cflogin.name) is ""))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, i decided to ditch cflogin and simply just go with a basic session based authentication.